# JS Statement for Client Side Alert in .aspx.vb

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, .aspxauth

I am fairly new to hard coding & VS.  I have successfully created a couple applications using .aspx so I am beginning to understand a little more.

I have a form (.aspx) which has a yes/no dropdown box, if the user selects yes, it's necessary to populate the following empty text box (TextBox13 "Reason/Comment").  And I need to add a CLIENT side alert message (using JS, I have found to be the answer) to which I have tried using samples I have found.  Problem is, none of the examples are for exactly what I need.

So far, I did create a .js page:

```
$('#MP_Form').submit(function(e) {
  if(!$.trim($(this).find('TextBox13'="text"').val()).length){
      e.preventDefault();
     alert('If critical, you must provide a reason/comment.');
    }
});
}
```

I added the  in my master page, and understand I need a statement in my aspx.vb page with a function.  I think the onSubmit is what I want but not sure how to write the if, then statement. Can someone please help me out?
Thanks!
Kathy

Comment: Replace `if(!$.trim($(this).find('TextBox13'="text"').val()).length){ `by `if(!$.trim($(this).find('input[type=text]').val()).length){`

Comment: There are errors in your syntax (look at your JavaScript console). If it doesn't fix your problem please post on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: What do you expect `.find('TextBox13'="text"')` to do?

Comment: You can also do this in your code-behind (.aspx.vb) page, either when your dropdown change or when you click on the send button. For example if the user select "No" you could simply hide the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/CgdL2/). There's an input and a button.
To get the text in the input I use the following:
`$('#inputId').val();`
In my case inputId is comment, so in my case it's `$('#comment').val();`

Comment: As I mentioned, I am quite new to writing the code out so I really am not completely understanding most of the js.  The VB I understand a bit more.  I tried both responses I received but when I run the page, it does run but does not provide an alert if yes is selected & a comment not provided.  If the user does provide a comment, upon the input button, it should redirect to the main forms & reports page to which all work fine except the client alert.

Comment: this is the .vb code behind
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        If (Not Master.Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("alert")) Then

            Master.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "insideJS();", True)

        End If

    End Sub

Comment: Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click
        If CriticalList.Text = "Yes" Then
            If TextBox13.Text <> "" Then
                SqlDataSource1.Insert()
                Response.Redirect("FormsReport.aspx")
            Else
                MsgBox("If you select Yes for Critical, you must provide a reason.")
            End If
        Else
            SqlDataSource1.Insert()
            Response.Redirect("FormsReport.aspx")
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: Protected Sub CriticalList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CriticalList.SelectedIndexChanged End Sub

Comment: can someone provide an example of how I would write  this in code behind?  I think I have gotten myself confused & know it's no where near as difficult as I think..  Please help.