# Code Behind Client Side Alert

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, client-side, code-behind

I previous asked for assistance but don't think I ask the right question.  I am new to coding & have a web app with a form on it which has a yes/no dropdown & a textbox after for a reason.  I managed to write the code behind for a msgbox but I need it on the client side.  I know it's not nearly as complicated as I thihk.  This is the code behind I used for the server side msgbox:

```
Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As Event Args) Handles SubmitButton.Click
If CriticalList.Text = "Yes" THEN
 If TextBox13.Text <> "" THEN
   SqlDataSource1.Insert()
 Response.Redirect("FormsReport.aspx")
ELSE
  MsgBox("If critical, you MUST provide a reason.")
 End IF
ELSE
   SqlDataSource1.Insert()
  Response.Redirect("FormsReport.aspx")
End IF
End SUB
```

Can someone, ANYONE please give me some guidance of how I would write this for a client side alert? Preferably in code behind.

Comment: This has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673795/call-javascript-from-vb-net-code-behind

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Statement for Client Side Alert in .aspx.vb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112270/js-statement-for-client-side-alert-in-aspx-vb)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim message As String = "If Critical, you MUST provide a reason."
Dim script As String = "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('" + message + "');</script>"
```

correction for the Above will be as this

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "AlertBox", script)
```

Dont forget the single qouts at the alert code

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d156d49-ea9a-4f58-a17f-228c9470ee7a/display-a-message-box-in-a-vbnet-web-application

this is one of the answers found on the link given above.  of course you will have to adapt it to your code a little bit.

```
Dim message As String = "If Critical, you MUST provide a reason."
Dim script As String = "<script type='text/javascript'> alert(" + message + ");</script>"

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "AlertBox", script)
```

I have not tested this code so I don't know that it works the way you intend it to,  please test